# How do I respond to ICMP requests with modified payload on linux (c++)

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming, iptables, netfilter

I have a netfilter-queue application that handles ICMP requests.
Under certain circumstances I want to change the payload that gets sent back to the client.

My code currently calls this:

```
 nfq_set_verdict(qh, id, verdict, ret, buffer);
```

I'm wondering if I can change the payload by simply changing the buffer.
I've been told that it is not possible to use Netfilter-queue to change the payload of an ICMP request.

Assuming that is true, what is the best/easiest way on a Linux machine to modify the payload of an ICMP response before sending it back to a client?

Comment: Have you tried doing it this way?  ip_queue/libipq (which netfilter replaces) definitely allowed what you describe.

Comment: What is your iptables rule you are using? You should be able to modify the packet and return it back via the nfq_set_verdict() method but I think it may need to be en-queued via the mangle table. Also, depending on what you modify, you may need to fix up some protocol checksums yourself.